# PHP Sort A Delimited Text File Alphabetically Then Populate Drop Down List

Tags: php, file, sorting, text, drop-down-menu

I am having a few issues in doing something that I am sure is quite simple.

I have had a look for many hours on Google and stackoverflow but I can't seem to find an answer. What I did find that was similar I tried to modify, but unfortunately without success.

I have a text file (names.txt) that contains values similar to this:

```
Jim|Bob|Keith|Fred|Steve<br>
```

I need a script that I can run every minute to change the content of the file to store the values in the same format but alphabetically:

```
Bob|Fred|Jim|Keith|Steve<br>
```

then display them in an html dropdown box as options.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `code`<?php
$file = file("names_active.txt");
sort($file);
$newContent = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
{
  $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
  $newContent .= $states[0] .''. $states[1] . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('names_active.txt',$newContent);
?>`code` This is what I have tried but Nikolaos has been a help with this one.

Comment: This is what I have tried for the drop-down menu: `code` <?php
// define file
$file = 'names.txt';

$handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
if ($handle) {
   while (!feof($handle)) {
       $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
       $item = explode('|', $line);
       echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0] . '</option>' . "\n";
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
?>`code` It only seems to show the first value in the file though. Any help really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - can't seem to get the code to display properly on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$fileName = 'names.txt';
$data     = file_get_contents($fileName);

// Assuming that the file had the data in one line...

// Split the data using the delimiter
$split = explode("|", $data);

// Sort
sort($split);

// Put it all back together
$data = implode("|", $split);

// Store it back in the file
file_put_contents($fileName, $data);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! When it moves around the values it seems to do strange things with the pipe delimiters and several end up at the front of the file depending on how many have been moved. With quite a few names they would stack up. Any ideas as to how we can keep them in the right place? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by strange things? Can you give an example on how the order is not kept? Bare in mind that memory operations like array creation, sorting etc. do have limits and if your list has thousands of elements you might see errors in the output.

Comment: I just kept adding to the file and sorting it with the script you provided and it seemed to sort itself out so not sure what it was doing but it seems to work! Many thanks for your assistance!